# Dealing with Daylight Savings Time in iOS

Tags: ios, datetime, uidatepicker

I am writing an calendar events based app for iOS and I have having a crazy time dealing with dates and daylight savings time.  I am using a date picker so the user can enter the event date and time.  When they do, and I ask for a description of the NSDate object, I get:

```
2015-01-13 17:34:47 +0000
```

Which does not contain a timezone offset but the offset has been applied (the set time is 1:34pm).  When I ask of the time zone on the NSDate object, I get:

```
America/New_York (EST) offset -18000
```

Which is right.

When I advance the date to a day in daylight savings time, I get:

```
2015-03-09 17:39:01 +0000
```

Also with no offset and is now wrong because the offset should be different (should be 16:39:01).  When I ask for the time zone, I get:

```
America/New_York (EST) offset -18000
```

Which is now wrong (should be EDT with an offset of -14400). But with I ask for the description with Locale on the NSDate object, I get:

```
Monday, March 9, 2015 at 1:39:01 PM Eastern Daylight Time
```

Which is right but not in a format that is very useful.

What am I doing wrong here? Does anyone know of a good source of info on this for iOS other the Apple's not very useful date/time programming guide?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted relevant code in your question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: what time did you enter on the picker in the DST case?